# Scrolling to text with accordion bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, accordion

I'm new to web development and decided to use Bootstrap on a personal website that I'm making. I want to have cards that expands to have more detail when a button is clicked, however when the accordion folders are closed the content is at the bottom of the page. This means that when the accordion is expanded the user may need to scroll to the see the content that is revealed or they otherwise might miss it. I know that with a button you can usually scroll to an element using its id, but since it is an accordion element when I try to do `href="#aboutCollapse"`, the webpage doesn't actually scroll to anything and I'm not sure why it happens.

This is the code from that section of the html:

```
<div class="accordion" id="infoGroup">
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card info-card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>About Me</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body info-text" id="card1">
                    <p class="card-text" style="height: 70%">I am a junior year computer science major who loves to create.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" href="#aboutCollapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aboutCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aboutCollapse">More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card info-card" id="card2">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>Projects</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body info-text">
                    <p class="card-text" style="height: 70%;">I work on a lot of projects. All my projects end up on Github.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projectsCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="projectsCollapse">More</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Open</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card info-card" id="card3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>Resume</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body info-text">
                    <p>My resume is where to get the most professional, up to date information about my career and personal achievements.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resumeCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="resumeCollapse">More</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="documents/Jeffrey Carr Resume.pdf" target="_blank">Open</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- More info from cards -->
        <div class="accordian-group">
            <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="aboutCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card1">
                    <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">About Me</h5>
                    <p class="collapse-card-text" >I don't really know how to talk about myself. Hopefully I'll be able to come up with enough to fill this space.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="projectsCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card2">
                <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">Projects</h5>
                <p class="collapse-card-text" >This section will show my most recent project. There will be a link to a separate projects page.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="resumeCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card3">
                <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">Resume</h5>
                <p class="collapse-card-text">This section will show the highlights of my resume</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any simple solution to make it so the webpage can scroll to show the beginning of the content? Also any other critiques of my html are welcome as I am learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how strict your design ideas are, but I'd put the accordion in my card to show further info. (SNIPPET 1)

If you really want to do two things at once (opening an accordion AND scrolling to a position) you may need to go the JS way (create a function that does both things for you). (SNIPPET 2) For this, you have to leave the `data-*` type control of the items, and create JavaScript (jQuery) functions.

### SNIPPET 1

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="accordion" id="infoGroup">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card info-card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5>About Me</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body info-text" id="card1">
              <p class="card-text" style="height: 70%">I am a junior year computer science major who loves to create.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" href="#aboutCollapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aboutCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aboutCollapse">More</button>
              <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="aboutCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card1">
                <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">About Me</h5>
                <p class="collapse-card-text">I don't really know how to talk about myself. Hopefully I'll be able to come up with enough to fill this space.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card info-card" id="card2">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5>Projects</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body info-text">
              <p class="card-text" style="height: 70%;">I work on a lot of projects. All my projects end up on Github.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projectsCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="projectsCollapse">More</button>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Open</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card info-card" id="card3">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5>Resume</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body info-text">
              <p>My resume is where to get the most professional, up to date information about my career and personal achievements.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resumeCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="resumeCollapse">More</button>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" href="documents/Jeffrey Carr Resume.pdf" target="_blank">Open</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- More info from cards -->
        <div class="accordian-group">
          <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="projectsCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card2">
            <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">Projects</h5>
            <p class="collapse-card-text">This section will show my most recent project. There will be a link to a separate projects page.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="resumeCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card3">
            <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">Resume</h5>
            <p class="collapse-card-text">This section will show the highlights of my resume</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### SNIPPET 2

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#toggleAboutCollapse').on('click', function(e) {
    // this prevents the webpage to jump to the anchor when you
    // clock on the link with the ID in the selector
    e.preventDefault()

    // this toggles the state of the accordion item
    $('#aboutCollapse').collapse('toggle')

    // this creates a smooth scroll effect on your page
    // 2000 ms (that's two seconds) may be a bit slow :)
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#aboutCollapse").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  })

})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="accordion" id="infoGroup">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card info-card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5>About Me</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body info-text" id="card1">
              <p class="card-text" style="height: 70%">I am a junior year computer science major who loves to create.</p>
              <button id="toggleAboutCollapse" class="btn btn-primary collapsed" href="#aboutCollapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aboutCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aboutCollapse">More</button>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card info-card" id="card2">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5>Projects</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body info-text">
              <p class="card-text" style="height: 70%;">I work on a lot of projects. All my projects end up on Github.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projectsCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="projectsCollapse">More</button>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Open</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card info-card" id="card3">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h5>Resume</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body info-text">
              <p>My resume is where to get the most professional, up to date information about my career and personal achievements.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resumeCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="resumeCollapse">More</button>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" href="documents/Jeffrey Carr Resume.pdf" target="_blank">Open</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- More info from cards -->
        <div class="accordian-group">
          <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="aboutCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card1">
            <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">About Me</h5>
            <p class="collapse-card-text">I don't really know how to talk about myself. Hopefully I'll be able to come up with enough to fill this space.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="projectsCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card2">
            <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">Projects</h5>
            <p class="collapse-card-text">This section will show my most recent project. There will be a link to a separate projects page.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse collapse-card" id="resumeCollapse" data-parent="#infoGroup" aria-labelledby="card3">
            <h5 class="border-bottom border-dark collapse-card-title">Resume</h5>
            <p class="collapse-card-text">This section will show the highlights of my resume</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason I'm not putting it in the cards is because I've kept them quite small so having a lot of text would be hard to read (about 18em width). The JS seems really cool but I'm having trouble getting it work and I'm sure it's something dumb that I'm doing. Here is the complete code I've used: https://liveweave.com/FFBbXd#&togetherjs=kfFum5yEUn

Comment: The code you shared from **liveweave.com** has two problems: 1. the bootstrap.css is not included; 2. the bootstrap.min.js is **slim**. You can copy these from the snippet I provided - the CSS from a CDN and the JS should NOT be slim. Then there's the order of things: your custom CSS and JS should come AFTER all the other sources, as otherwise you cannot overwrite them with your custom code.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your patience! I kept the bootstrap css in the head, the slim js was definitely the problem. In practice is putting the scripts at the top of the body better than including it at the bottom?

Comment: The convention is that CSS should be in the `<head>`, JS should be just before `</body>`. CSS should be before the element it formats, so when the element is rendered it's already formatted. JS should be after the element it "controls", as it cannot control a not-yet-existing element. But it really depends on how you need your code and how it works the best.

Comment: And it's funny that jQuery **slim** is there with Bootstrap - a lot of commonly used functions do not work with the **slim** version.